# How to intent fragment to activity once clicked recycler list item with in fragment and how to get the recycler item value?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, android-recyclerview

I here by attached my code.

1. I have a fragment with in that have recycler list item list.
2. If i click the recycler item on fragment i can't move to new activity.
3. And i want to get the recycler item value which item i have clicked.

So kindly please suggest me to how to intent fragment to activity once clicked recycler list item with in fragment and how to get the recycler item value?

**ContactOneFragment**

```
public class ContactOneFragment extends Fragment {

    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contactone, null, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        DetailModel detail[] = {
                new DetailModel("Meenakshi.A","9566415797"),
                new DetailModel("Pandimurugeswari.S","8940144873"),
                new DetailModel("Selvam. K","7708410451"),
                new DetailModel("Raja Lakshmi.V","9952754812"),
                new DetailModel("Narmatha Devi.S","9894762259"),
                new DetailModel("Murugan.M","9566368816"),
                new DetailModel("SenthilMurugan.A","7667453595"),
        };

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        DetailAdapter mAdapter = new DetailAdapter(detail);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        return view;
     }
}
```

**DetailAdapter**

```
public class DetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private DetailModel[] itemsData;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    Context context;

    public DetailAdapter(DetailModel[] itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public DetailAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.contactnamenumber, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

        viewHolder.namelist.setText(itemsData[position].getName());
        viewHolder.numberlist.setText(itemsData[position].getNumber());
        //  viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
        // viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setTag(new Integer(position));
    }


    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView namelist;
        public TextView numberlist;
        String name;
        String number;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            namelist = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            numberlist = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
            //imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            name=namelist.getText().toString();
            number=numberlist.getText().toString();
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.length;
    }
} //Update - Code formatting
```

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/4281182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your constructor `DetailAdapter` as following:

```
public DetailAdapter(Context context, DetailModel[] itemsData) {
  this.context = context;
  this.itemsData = itemsData;
}
```

On your `onClick()` method in adapter add following code:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) {
    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
    String tempName = itemsData[pos].getName();
    String tempNumber = itemsData[pos].getNumber();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Accept the answer if you are solved. @karthik

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your adapter,

```
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OrderClickListener();
```

then

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contactnamenumber, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

now in adapter,

```
 private class OrderClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mOrderSelect.onOrderSelect(rvOrderHistory.getChildLayoutPosition(v));
    }
}
```

From above steps you can get the position which item is clicked. Here you can go to next activity.